# Spring WebClient get request return "Connection refused: localhost/"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

When I'm trying to send GET request with WebClient, I have responce with error io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/

*** WebClient initialization ***

```
//hostname = "localhost/127.0.0.1:8081"
//contextPath = "user-service"

    @Bean
    public WebClient userWebclient(@Value("${service.user.hostname}") final String hostname,
                                  @Value("${service.user.contextPath}") final String contextPath) {
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl(hostname + contextPath)
                .build();
    }
```

*** Controller ***

```
    private final WebClient userWebclient;

    @GetMapping(value = "/user/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> getUserById(@NotNull @PathVariable String userId) {
        userWebclient.

        return userWebclient.get()
               .uri("/UserMock/user/" + userId)
               .header("Accept", "application/json")
               .header("Authorization", "Bearer =........")
               .exchange()
               .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class));
    }
```

***Error message***

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:665)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your address for correctness, this error can be because of your port number isn't correct like 8081, but should be 8080

Comment: crap! you're right, my port isn't correct, it should be 8181.

Answer (score 0):

In host use either

```
hostname = "localhost:8081"
```

OR

```
hostname = "127.0.0.1:8081"
```

Instead of

```
hostname = "localhost/127.0.0.1:8081"
```